# How to limit tabnine's memory usage?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I install the tabnine extension in vscode, the tool is great however it occupy memory over 1G. My computer is lagging. Is there any way to limit tabnine's memory usage or general vscode extensions' memory usage

Answer (score 1):

In linux is possible with the tool called "timeout". When you start vscode automatically is created one specify process for tabnine. With this tool is possible limit the RAM usage of one process

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use Tabnine Cloud, Tabnine will send blocks of code from your edited files to our server, allowing us to provide deep completion suggestions. These blocks of code will never be stored - they are used to calculate predictions and then immediately discarded.
We recommend the cloud version to optimize RAM usage if you have a stable internet connection.

Ref: [Optimize RAM usage](https://support.tabnine.com/hc/en-us/articles/4413885106321-Optimize-RAM-usage)